# What permission enables the SharePoint-Document lookup control?

Tags: sharepoint-online, dynamics-crm-online

I have a table with a column that is a reference to the SharePoint-Document table in Dynamics 365 CRM. This field is placed on the model-driven app form. However, certain users have it locked (read-only) while others don't. I suspect this issue is related to security roles and permissions. What specific permission or security role settings are needed to give users edit access to this field?

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the users have at least "Create," "Read," "Write," and "Append" privileges for the SharePoint-Document entity. These permissions are necessary to enable editing of fields associated with the SharePoint-Document table

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the current policies since all of your recent answers appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).   As a heads-up, [posting of AI-generated content is not permitted on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831).

Comment: If you used an AI tool for assistance on this answer, could I ask you to (1) Reply in a comment here confirming that it was AI-generated, along with what tool (e.g., ChatGPT, Bing Chat, Copilot, etc.) -- We're compiling data on AI-assisted answers and could use your help. (2) After commenting, I recommend deleting your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Comment: @rizwan-ahmed  SharePoint-Document table is not listed. Only SharePoint document location and SharePoint Website